# Unity Vuforia AR: 3D Object Position Shifts Unexpectedly After Interaction

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, duplicates, position, vuforia

**Hello everyone,**

I'm working with Unity and Vuforia for an augmented reality project. I've utilized "**ground plane stage**" and "**plane finder**". The issue I'm encountering is that when I tap on my phone screen to display a 3D object, it appears correctly. However, if I tap on the object again, its position shifts unexpectedly. I'm unsure how to address this problem.

Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: On which platform are you seeing this? iOS, Android? Are you using the Vuforia Sample? If not I would check if you can reproduce the problem there.

Comment: yes, I used Android and the Vuforia sample

Comment: Which Unity and Vuforia version? And, are "Google Play Services for AR" up to date on the device?

Comment: The Vuforia version is 10.16.5, and for Unity, I'm using 2022.3.5f1. Regarding 'Google Play Services for AR,' they are up-to-date on the device.

Comment: this looks like a bug. I would file an issue here https://github.com/PTCInc/vuforia-engine